# Сигнатура метода, принимающего две матрицы обобщенного типа

Tags: java

Хочу написать метод, который будет принимать две матрицы обобщенного типа , и возвращать другую матрицу того же типа. Я не знаю как правильно указать необходимую мне сигнатуру метода. Полистал Хортсманна и интернет, ответа на свой вопрос не нашел.

```
public class MatrixMultiplication
{
public static Result<T> matrixMult(Matrix<T extends Number> one, Matrix<T extends Number> two)
{

}
}
```

Или я должен принимать две матрицы Object[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип `<T extends Number>` указывается перед возвращаемым значением

```
public class MatrixMultiplication {
    public static <T extends Number> Result<T> matrixMult(Matrix<T> one, Matrix<T> two)
    {
     //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Matrix cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - Result cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - Matrix cannot be resolved 
  to a type
. У меня в программе нет еще никаких либо классов, в том числе и Matrix, и быть не должно. Я написал код лишь потому, что так положено на оверфлоу, и я почти уверен что не верный. Мне нужно избежать создания классов Matrix и Result. Мой метод просто должен принять две матрицы обобщенного типа, наследованных от Number

Comment: А это уже другой вопрос. Ищите библиотеки для работы с матрицами и подключайте. Например есть такая: http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download

Comment: Я не должен искать сторонние библиотеки. Я должен написать алгоритм сам. Метод должен принять две матрицы обобщенного типа и вернуть матрицу обобщенного типа. Это все требование

Comment: в таком случае и класс матриц сами реализуйте

Comment: Без этого никак нельзя обойтись? Что будет если я приму два массива типа Object?

Comment: Вообще вы можете подключить библиотеку, воспользоваться их классом матрицы, но сам алгоритм реализовать по своему. В JDK8 нет классов поддерживающих матрицы.